Identifying delegatecalls to a target contract
A contract I am auditing (contract A) is being used via delegate call by another contract. I suspect there may be more contracts using this code as well in the same manner but I cannot prove it.
Is there any way I can identify contracts that are making delegatecalls to contract A? Are there any traces left of a delegatecall akin to internal transactions?
Unfortunately, these transactions do not emit any events, which was a way I could use to spot them otherwise.

One way is to review the bytecode of other contracts that are making delegate calls to contract A. Look for occurrences of the DELEGATECALL opcode (0xf4). This opcode is used to delegate a call to another contract while preserving the current contract's context.
